# vectorizing for loop that does a sum

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization

Greetings All

How can I vectorizing this for loop?

```
t_rebuilt=linspace(0,1,length(inner_freq));

for ii=1:1:length(inner_freq)-1;ii=ii+1; 

    aa_sig_rebuilt=inner_freq(ii,2)*cos(2*pi*t_rebuilt*inner_freq(ii,1)+inner_freq(ii,3));
    aa_sig_combined=aa_sig_combined+aa_sig_rebuilt;

end;
```

I tried replacing it with the line below to see if it worked but I just get a straight line

`aa_sig_rebuilt=inner_freq(ii,2).*cos(2*pi*t_rebuilt*inner_freq(ii,1)+inner_freq(ii,3));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `t_rebuilt` is a 1-by-N vector of time points at which you want to evaluate a set of trigonometric functions with parameters defined in the rows of the M-by-3 matrix `inner_freq`. Then you want to add all these results into a single combined signal. You can do this without a for loop as follows:

```
temp = 2*pi*inner_freq(:,1)*t_rebuilt;  %# This matrix multiplication will
                                        %#   result in an M-by-N matrix
temp = temp+repmat(inner_freq(:,3),1,numel(t_rebuilt));  %# Replicate and add
                                                         %#   column 3
aa_sig_combined = inner_freq(:,2).'*cos(temp);  %'# Gives you your 1-by-N
                                                 %#   combined signal
```

You can then plot the result as follows:

```
plot(t_rebuilt,aa_sig_combined);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sum(aa_sig_rebuilt=inner_freq(:,2).*cos(2*pi*t_rebuilt*inner_freq(:,1)+inner_freq(:,3)));
```

Comment: t_rebuilt=linspace(0,1,length(inner_freq)); so it's another array I plotted it and the plot came back as a straight line